# Error with siunitx/translator and pgfcalendar

Tags: pgfplots, siunitx, pgfplotstable, translator

I was trying to produce a table with `pgfplotstable` and the `date type` style in one column. For this the package `pgfcalendar` is necessary.
If I include also the `siunitx` package a strange error occurs.
Here are the last few lines of the logfile. It looks like that the `\DeclareSIUnit` command is not working properly.

```
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx-abbreviations.cfg")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx-abbreviations.cfg"
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...

l.18 \DeclareSIUnit
                  \A  {        \ampere }
?

Process has been terminated ...
```

Here is a MWE which produces the error. I tried to compile with `pdflatex`, `lualatex` and `xelatex`. For all the same error message.

```
    \documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{filecontents}{dataA.csv}
pH;     concentration; date
1;     1.5;     2015-04-04
2;      -0.5;    2015-05-05
3;      -1.5;   2015-06-06
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableset{col sep=semicolon}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={pH, concentration, date},fixed zerofill, 
                        %columns/date/.style={string type},
                        columns/date/.style={date type={\day.\month.\year}},
                        ]{dataA.csv}



\end{document}
```

Maybe `pgfcalendar` redefines a basic macro `siunitx` is using.
Is it a bug of one package or is there something I missed?

UPDATE:
The error occurs probably due to the `translator` package of the `beamer` class which is automatically loaded by `siunitx`.

Comment: For strange reasons, `siunitx-abbreviations.cfg` is loaded again when the table is being typeset, causing the error.

Comment: Disabling the loading of the abbreviations file leads to a more serious error, that has to do with the translation modules.